# upload Yii application to server

Tags: php, css, yii

I developed a yii web application, and I changed the default css even I changed the images, but after I uploaded into my server which I hosted from bluhost, the Gridview css does not changed and the default images for icons(updare,View,delete) are still there.
what I did is I uploaded my wep application folder and yii framework folder.

So can you help me what is going wrong

Comment: How did you set the address of your css file?

Comment: Are the css files you edited located in the `assets` folder?

Comment: my css file  are in css folder near to assets not inside,

Answer (score 0):

You can disable default css by adding 'cssFile'=>false in Your CGridView widget. You can also add path to Your css file instead of false value.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'model-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'cssFile'=>false,
// 'cssFile'=>'path_to_your/file.css',
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks gSorry, but the problem is I edited the default css which is inside assets and I created another css folder also to add my custom css, the problem is all that css that I changed is not taking effect and I am getting the default blue style.

Comment: All files in assets folder are temporary. When You transfer app to another server, app generates new files in assets folder then Your changes doesn't take effects anymore. You should always write your own css file. Overwrite styles in it and load it after default styles from assets..